# Getting java.lang.StackOverflowError while matching regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Pattern I am using is,

```
Pattern listPattern = Pattern.compile(
            "\\s*'([^']*('')*)+'\\s*(,\\s*'([^']*('')*)+'\\s*)*"
                    + "|"
                    + "\\s*[0-9\\.\\-]+(,\\s*[0-9\\.-]+)*\\s*",
            Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

this pattern is needed to verify whether input is correct for adding to in() clause in sql query, & values are like,

```
String value="'xyz2006201257200426888282d','xyz2006201300193058314082d'";
```

here i used just 2 ids but when this ids (ex. xyz2006201257200426888282d) are more in number (~ >600 ), i am getting stack-overflow exception.
Can somebody help with the inefficiency in regular expression pattern because of which stack overflow is happening?

stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Character.codePointAt(Character.java:4866)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3775)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4250)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4485)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4405)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4801)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4741)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4794)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4485)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4405)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4485)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4405)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4801)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4741)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4794)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4485)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4405)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4485)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4405)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace for the exception you're receiving.

Comment: Replacing all `(` with `(?:` should reduce the overhead while the regex engine traverses the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your basic problem is this clause `([^']*('')*)+`
It probably adds more steps than necessary.

***update:***
You can replace it with an unrolled-loop version that will significantly
reduce the overall steps. `[^']*(?:''[^']*)*`

Rewriting the regex it now becomes

```
"(\\s*'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'(?:\\s*,\\s*'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*')*\\s*)|(\\s*[0-9.-]+(?:,\\s*[0-9.-]+)*\\s*)"
```

At this demo, the target is 800 `'xyz2006201257200426888282d'` separated by
comma's. It takes 8010 steps.

https://regex101.com/r/WVrPBb/1

Give it a try, worse case it stack overflows.

Readable version

```
    (                             # (1 start)
         \s* 
         '
         [^']* 
         (?: '' [^']* )*
         ' 
         (?:
              \s* , \s* 
              '
              [^']* 
              (?: '' [^']* )*
              ' 
         )*
         \s* 
    )                             # (1 end)
 |  
    (                             # (2 start)
         \s* 
         [0-9.-]+ 
         (?:
              , \s* [0-9.-]+ 
         )*
         \s* 
    )                             # (2 end)
```

Comment: still getting stack overflow exception☹.

Comment: Please explain your reasoning

Comment: @dhanu10896 - Added an update using an unrolled-loop. Probably, this is the best you can do. Also, If you have weird data, you could make all cluster groups atomic if need be. Ie. change all `(?:` to `(?>`